# How to write a shell script for printing the PID and The owner and the Name of the Process using the Special Variable $$ as parameter for the skript

Tags: bash, scripts, process, sh

The script shall present the command `pstree -hsup $$`.
I have tried many different ways but I couldn't find a way to print the output like this

```
28348 (bash,root)
28347 (su,root)
28346 (sudo,root)
14085 (bash,user)
14083 (lxterminal,user)
    1 (Systemd,root)
```

Comment: Something like ``pstree -hsupA $$ | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/-[+-]-\| *[`|]-/\n/g'``? How should the output be sorted?

Comment: it should be sorted from the newest process to the oldest including  the name of the owner and in the shell script i can't use the pstree command , i just want to printout the process from the current shell like (./shell.sh $$) it should print the processes and the PID and the the owner in this way PID (NAME,OWNER)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps -o ppid` will output the pid of the parent process. So, start with the current pid, and ask for the parent, then for its parent, and so on.

```
#! /bin/bash
pid=$1
while ((pid)) ; do
    ps -h -o 'pid,comm,euser' $pid \
        | sed -E 's/^( *[0-9]+ )([^ ]+) *([^ ]+)/\1(\2,\3)/'
    pid=$(ps -h -o ppid $pid)
done
```

You want to output pid, the command, and the effective user (or maybe real user?). Specify them in the `-o` and use `sed` to reformat the output. Here, we capture the three non-space strings and insert parentheses and a comma where needed.